# Pass a checkbox group bind from the child to the parent in Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to pass an input checkbox group bind from the child to the parent, but I'm struggling to make it work.

What I want to happen is that every time a user clicks on the checkbox, and Svelte automatically updates the group:bind, I want to pass that update to the parent and store the change in an array that I can access for components sitting on the parent.

So in my child component, I have

```
<script>
export let dataItem;
export let value = [];
</script>

 <input type="checkbox" bind:group={value} name="{dataItem}" id="{dataItem}" value="{dataItem}" class="absolute h-0 w-0 appearance-none focus:ring-0 focus:ring-offset-0" />
```

Then in the parent, I've tried to bind to the value:

```
<Card bind:value/>
```

but that doesn't seem to work, and I also can't access that value.

I've tried to look at event dispatching.

```
<script>
import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
 let dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
export let dataItem;
export let value = [];

const handleClick = (value) => {
        console.log(value)
        selected = [...selected, value]
        console.log({selected})
        dispatch('clickCard', {value})
    }
</script>

 <input type="checkbox" on:click={handleClick} bind:group={value} name="{dataItem}" id="{dataItem}" value="{dataItem}" class="absolute h-0 w-0 appearance-none focus:ring-0 focus:ring-offset-0" />
```

but I can't seem to pass the value to the parent trying that either.

I would gratefully receive any ideas to point me in the right direction, please

Comment: the `bind:value` should work, just make sure that `value` is defined in the parent.

Comment: @StephaneVanraes Unfortunately it seems to only work properly if all elements that use the group binding exist in the same component. It may [behave like radio buttons](https://svelte.dev/repl/46683837b4c540f988d673571901603e?version=3.49.0) otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With events you can just directly forward the click event:

```html
<input type=checkbox ... on:click />
```

Then when handling the event you can get the checkbox from the `target` and update your list of values (though a `Set` makes this easier):

```html
<Child ... on:click={onClick} />
```

```js
let values = new Set();

function onClick(e) {
    const cb = e.target;
    if (cb.checked)
        values.add(cb.value);
    else
        values.delete(cb.value);

    values = values;
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9928dbd372c946f3abd9aadadec46164?version=3.49.0)

If you use the dispatcher, your data will be in the `details` property and you will need to pass the value and the checked state, because the event will not be associated the checkbox.

---

An alternative would be to [set a context](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) to a store that holds the values, then each child component can add/remove its value to/from that.

Comment: Perfect, thank you - event forwarding worked. It is strange I can't seem to utilise the group bind or dynamically update a parent array from it

Comment: `group` probably requires the compiler to "see" all items in the same place, so it will not work when split up like this.